# Invoke grc terminal colorizer on ALL commands implicitly

Tags: terminal, xterm, colorize, text-coloring, ansi-colors

I love the grc colorizer for the terminal. However I have to explicitly prefix anything I want colorized with:

```
grc --config=conf.mine
```

Is there any way to have it automatically applied to everything you input on the command line (so that potentially I don't even need to know what grc is)? Perhaps using shell hooks, if a better alternative doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [grc.bashrc](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc.bashrc) and [grc.zsh](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc.zsh) files provided with grc since v1.9 does this in a (non-complete) way by adding aliases for common commands:

**grc.bashrc**

```
GRC=`which grc`
if [ "$TERM" != dumb ] && [ -n "$GRC" ]
then
    alias colourify="$GRC -es --colour=auto"
    alias configure='colourify ./configure'
    alias diff='colourify diff'
    alias make='colourify make'
    alias gcc='colourify gcc'
    alias g++='colourify g++'
    alias as='colourify as'
    alias gas='colourify gas'
    alias ld='colourify ld'
    alias netstat='colourify netstat'
    alias ping='colourify ping'
    alias traceroute='colourify /usr/sbin/traceroute'
    alias head='colourify head'
    alias tail='colourify tail'
    alias dig='colourify dig'
    alias mount='colourify mount'
    alias ps='colourify ps'
    alias mtr='colourify mtr'
    alias df='colourify df'
fi
```

**grc.zsh**

```
if [[ "$TERM" != dumb ]] && (( $+commands[grc] )) ; then
  # Prevent grc aliases from overriding zsh completions.
  setopt COMPLETE_ALIASES

  # Supported commands
  cmds=(
    cc \
    configure \
    cvs \
    df \
    diff \
    dig \
    gcc \
    gmake \
    ifconfig \
    last \
    ldap \
    ls \
    make \
    mount \
    mtr \
    netstat \
    ping \
    ping6 \
    ps \
    traceroute \
    traceroute6 \
    wdiff \
  );

  # Set alias for available commands.
  for cmd in $cmds ; do
    if (( $+commands[$cmd] )) ; then
      alias $cmd="grc --colour=auto $cmd"
    fi
  done

  # Clean up variables
  unset cmds cmd
fi
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried this, and it worked for me:

```
alias ls="ls -FHG"
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about that? How does defining an alias solve the given problem?